# Calculating the $n$th Moment of a Random Variable

Tags: probability

I have read that the $n$th moment of a random variable is defined as

$$\mathbb(E)[X^n] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^n f_X(x) \, dx$$

where

$$f_X(x) \sim \mathbb(P)[X = x]$$

My question is why does the preceding line hold true instead of

$$f_X(x^n) \sim \mathbb(P)[X = x^n].$$

In addition, is it possible to find the $n$th moment using the tailsum formula for the first moment?

$$\mathbb(E)[X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty 1 - F_X(x) \, dx$$

where

$$F_X(x) = \int f_X(x) \, dx$$

Comment: how is the relation ~ defined?

Comment: I meant f(x) as the probability density function.

Comment: Where you wrote $ \displaystyle F_X(x) = \int f_X(x)\,dx$ you need $ \displaystyle F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_X(u) \, du. $ To the right of the $\text{“} = \text{''},$ the place where the $\text{“} x \text{''}$ belongs is in $\displaystyle \text{“} \int_{-\infty}^x \text{''}. \qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A probability density function $f_X$ of a random variable $X$ is not characterized by $f_X(x) = \Pr(X=x),$ but by
$$
\Pr(X\in A) = \int_A f_X(x)\,dx
$$
for every measurable set $A.$ The same notation, $f_X,$ is used for probability mass functions of discrete random variables, for which we have $\Pr(X=x) = f_X(x)$ for every $x$ in the domain of $f_X.$

The expected value of a random variable with a density function is given by
$$
\operatorname E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f_X(x)\,dx.
$$
Now suppose $g$ is some function for which $\operatorname E(g(X))$ exists. Then we have
\begin{align}
& \operatorname E(g(X)) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f_{g(X)}(x) \, dx \tag 1 \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) f_X(x)\, dx. \tag 2
\end{align}
Equality the integrals in lines $(1)$ and $(2)$ is sometimes called the "law of the unconscious statistician." When I finished my Ph.D. in statistics I had never heard that term although I was well aware of the equality.

For example, $$ \operatorname E(X^2) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f_{X^2}(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 f_X(x)\, dx. $$

The reason for using the form on line $(2)$ above is that it is usually simpler.

Possibly someone has posted a request for a proof here, so you might find it there.

Comment: So you actually were an unconscious statistician who was unconscious about the name the law of the unconscious statistician?

Comment: Why is the third equation not equal to $$\int g(x) f_{g(x)}(g(x))$$? If we parameterize it such that $$Y = g(X)$$ wouldn’t we have the normal expectation formula?

Comment: @Sentient : Nothing called $f_{g(x)}$ is involved; the density function for the random variable $g(X)$ is $f_{g(X)},$ not $f_{g(x)}.$ You can get very confused by not attending to that.

Comment: @Sentient : I don't know what you're calling "the third equation".

Comment: @Sentient : $$ \operatorname E(Y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f_Y(x) \, dx, $$ $$ \text{i.e. } \operatorname E(g(X)) = \int_{-\infty} x f_{g(X)} (x) \, dx. $$